# Arraylist de int[] em java

Tags: java, collection

Estou criando uma list a partir de um `array` usando o método `Arrays.asList`.

Agora eu quero remover o primeiro elemento, mas o Java acusa:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

```
List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 } );
lista.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O método [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) retorna uma **lista de tamanho fixo**. [Vide documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

Ou seja, você não pode adicionar elementos nela, não pode remover elementos dela e não pode mexer na estrutura dela.

Você pode simplesmente criar um `ArrayList` a partir desta lista retornada pelo método `Arrays.asList`.

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 } ));        
lista.remove(0);
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso221163)